# UDP Loadbalancing Alternative in EKS

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, load-balancing, amazon-eks

It's come to my attention that NLB does not support UDP, or any other type of LoadBalancer on AWS. I am deploying an application on Kubernetes with the following constraints:

- I need multiple pods running on multiple node, not using host networking
- I need to route traffic (UDP/TCP) to this deployment
- The pods should be used interchangeably (a given user's traffic might be routed to pod A on node 1 or pod B on node 2, and I shouldn't have to worry)
- It doesn't have to give me a static IP / AWS NLB domain / or a given domain, as long as the LoadBalancer gives me something to connect to my pods through, I don't care what it looks like.

Any guidance would be appreciate!

Comment: EKS now supports UDP when using NLBs. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/08/amazon-eks-now-supports-udp-load-balancing-with-network-load-balancer/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like UDP LBs are on the roadmap for AWS, but still unavailable according to [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=264282). But DNS round-robin, and setting up your own LB are common approaches mentioned in the [community](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/8tirpw/udp_load_balancing_in_aws/) to address the lack of UDP support for AWS LB services.

Hope this helps!